# Why MySQL calculate this wrong way?

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
id - COL 17 - COL 2 - den - COL 54 - brutddssled - COL 42decimal - COL 45decimal - evrosum - 119546 - 4559 - SI - 2014-11-06 - 00012 Motorway toll - 7.800 - 12.500 - 2.760 - 45.780
```

Numbers are decimal 20,3.
When i try to SUM 12.500+2.760 MySQL says it is **45.780.** How is that possible?

My SELECT query is:

```
SELECT `id`,`COL 17`,`COL 2`,`den`,
       `COL 54`,`brutddssled`,`COL 42decimal`,
       `COL 45decimal`,  SUM(12.500+2.760) as evrosum 
FROM `fakturi_copy` 
WHERE `COL 17`="4559" 
AND `den` BETWEEN "2014-10-27" AND "2014-11-07" AND `COL 2`="SI"
```

Comment: What you mean, how do you help me?

Comment: 1. See normalisation. This is *the* fundamental concept of (SQL) databases.

Comment: Ok, thank you i will. But you mean because table is not good structured and SUM function calculate wrong way?

Comment: If you want to add two values from two different columns in the same row, that's just '+', not SUM(). SUM() is an aggregate function for adding together values in multiple rows of the same column. It is normally used in conjunction with a GROUP BY clause

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, you solve my issue now. Case is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Strawberry have write it in a comment. I need to sum values only by + sign no with function.
So the code is now this:

```
My SELECT query is:

SELECT `id`,`COL 17`,`COL 2`,`den`,
       `COL 54`,`brutddssled`,`COL 42decimal`,
       `COL 45decimal`,  12.500+2.760 as evrosum 
FROM `fakturi_copy` 
WHERE `COL 17`="4559" 
AND `den` BETWEEN "2014-10-27" AND "2014-11-07" AND `COL 2`="SI"
```